# fastai cnn_learner output table of fit_one_cycle()

Tags: python, neural-network, fast-ai

I have trained a CNN using fastai on Kaggle and also on my local machine. After calling `learn.fit_one_cycle(1)` on Kaggle I get the following table as output:

[image]

I executed the exact same code on my local machine (with Spyder ide and Python 3.7) and everything works, but I cannot see that output table. How can I display it?

This is the complete code:

```
from fastai import *
from fastai.vision import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg

bs = 32

path = 'C:\\DB\\UCMerced_LandUse\\UCMerced_LandUse\\Unfoldered_Images'

pat = r"([^/\d]+)[^/]*$"
fnames = get_image_files(path)

data = ImageDataBunch.from_name_re(path, fnames, pat, ds_tfms=get_transforms(), 
                                  size = 224, bs = bs, num_workers = 0).normalize(imagenet_stats)

learn = cnn_learner(data, models.resnet34, metrics=[accuracy])

learn.fit_one_cycle(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the console in Spyder was set to 'execute in current console' which doesn't seem to be able to displaye the result table. Setting it to 'execute in an external system terminal' solved the problem.